# Explain the instance properties of System.Net.IPAddress

Tags: c#, .net, ip-address, ipv6, system.net

I'm having a little trouble understanding the [`System.Net.IPAddress` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.aspx), because I don't know where to look for a definition of what some of the properties are referring to.  Specifically, what are:

```
 IPAddress.IsIPv6LinkLocal
 IPAddress.IsIPv6Multicast
 IPAddress.IsIPv6SiteLocal
 IPAddress.IsIPv6Teredo
```

I will also happily accept an answer that points to a resource that explains these concepts.  The MSDN site has proved insufficient.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[IPAddress.IsIPv6LinkLocal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address)

> A link-local address is an IP address
>   that is intended only for
>   communications within the local
>   subnetwork. Routers do not forward
>   packets with link-local addresses.

[IPAddress.IsIPv6Multicast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address)

> A multicast address is a logical
>   identifier for a group of hosts in a
>   computer network, that are available
>   to process datagrams or frames
>   intended to be multicast for a
>   designated network service. Multicast
>   addressing can be used in the Link
>   Layer (Layer 2 in the OSI model), such
>   as Ethernet multicast, and at the
>   Internet Layer (Layer 3 for OSI) for
>   Internet Protocol Version 4 (IPv4) or
>   Version 6 (IPv6) multicast.

[IPAddress.IsIPv6SiteLocal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Site-local_address)

> A unique local address (ULA) is an
>   IPv6 address in the block fc00::/7,
>   defined in RFC 4193. It is the IPv6
>   counterpart of the IPv4 private
>   address. Unique local addresses are
>   available for use in private networks,
>   e.g. inside a single site or
>   organisation, or spanning a limited
>   number of sites or organisations. They
>   are not routable in the global IPv6
>   Internet.

[IPAddress.IsIPv6Teredo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teredo_tunneling)

> In computer networking, Teredo is a
>   transition technology that gives full
>   IPv6 connectivity for IPv6-capable
>   hosts which are on the IPv4 Internet
>   but which have no direct native
>   connection to an IPv6 network.
>   Compared to other similar protocols
>   its distinguishing feature is that it
>   is able to perform its function even
>   from behind network address
>   translation (NAT) devices such as home
>   routers.

Answer (score 6):

The answer of CodeNaked is almost correct, but please watch out with IPAddress.IsIPv6SiteLocal. The original IPv6 Site Local addresses (fec0::/10) are deprecated.

These days Unique Local Addresses (ULA) are used in place of Site Local. ULA has two variants: fc00::/8 is not defined yet, but might be used in the future for internal-use addresses that are registered in a central place (ULA Central). fd00::/8 is in use and does not have to registered anywhere. Prefixes from this range are generated randomly.

Unfortunately IsIPv6SiteLocal only checks for the original deprecated version:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> [System.Net.IPAddress]'fec0::'

Address           :
AddressFamily     : InterNetworkV6
ScopeId           : 0
IsIPv6Multicast   : False
IsIPv6LinkLocal   : False
IsIPv6SiteLocal   : True
IPAddressToString : fec0::
```

It does not recognize ULA Central:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> [System.Net.IPAddress]'fc00::'

Address           :
AddressFamily     : InterNetworkV6
ScopeId           : 0
IsIPv6Multicast   : False
IsIPv6LinkLocal   : False
IsIPv6SiteLocal   : False
IPAddressToString : fc00::
```

Or locally assigned ULA:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> [System.Net.IPAddress]'fd00::'

Address           :
AddressFamily     : InterNetworkV6
ScopeId           : 0
IsIPv6Multicast   : False
IsIPv6LinkLocal   : False
IsIPv6SiteLocal   : False
IPAddressToString : fd00::
```

Please see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4193 for further details.

Answer (score 0):

For link local and site local:

http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_IPv6SpecialAddressesReservedPrivateLinkLocalSiteLo-3.htm

For link local, site local and multicast (and others as well):

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757359(WS.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757359%28WS.10%29.aspx)

For teredo:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457011.aspx

HTH